# Sugar ORM : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, android-studio, sugarorm

I am using SUGAR `ORM`, I want to do Sum of column"value" but getting this **error**.

Please help.

```
String whereCondition ="Select unique_id, name, Sum(value), type, category_type, note, nutrient_code from NUTRIENTS group by unique_id";

List<Nutrients> nutrientsList = Nutrients.findWithQuery(Nutrients.class, whereCondition);
```

Comment: Add your error output so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum(value) does not work with SugarORM directly. For that we need to use SQL raw query which is as follows:

```
 String whereCondition ="Select unique_id, name, Sum(value), type, category_type, note, nutrient_code from NUTRIENTS group by unique_id";

    Field f = null;
    try {
        f = SugarContext.getSugarContext().getClass().getDeclaredField("sugarDb");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        SugarDb db = (SugarDb) f.get(SugarContext.getSugarContext());
        Cursor cursor = db.getDB().
                rawQuery(whereCondition, null);
```